# Dynamic allocation of CPUs to threads with multithreading at runtime

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu, python-multithreading

**The general use case:**
I want to parallelize the executions of a Python script with multiple inputs. The inputs are wordlists (.txt files) of different sizes (from 2.000 to 3.000.000 rows).
**The setup:**
The scripts are executed on a server with 6 CPUs and 32GB RAM.
**The code snippet:**

```
wordlists = os.listdir(PATH_TO_WORDLISTS)
number_of_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    
# initialize pool with all CPUs available
p = multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_cpus)
# map function to inputs to create the threads
p.map(start, wordlists)
```

FYI: `start` is the function that starts the processing of the wordlist and the `worlists` parameter is a list of all the wordlist file names.
**The problem:**
The threads running the script with the smaller wordlists are done fairly quickly. With the code provided above, these 'quicker' threads are done in a certain amount of time with one thread being left running, the one having the wordlist with 3 million entries as input. 
Now, one CPU is working the thread and the other 5 CPUs are idle.
**The question:**
How can I alter the script that, as soon as there are no threads left to execute, the idle CPUs will be allocated (is that the right word?) to the still running threads?
For clarification: I understood the logic of the `map` function that way: it creates some kind of queue of threads that will be executed, so if one thread is done, the next thread in the queue will be started on the now free CPU. But in my problem there is no thread left in the queue, but I want to other five, idle CPUs to 'jump in' to help the one CPU executing the thread with the huge input.

Comment: You need to split your input work list in smaller items so to improve the load balancing. `map` is a simple primitive but there are other lower level solution to do that which can be more efficient regarding the use-case. You can use a [multiprocessing queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) so to better control the work sent to processes. The number of task to send needs not to be too big though because this queue have an overhead.

Comment: From the code you showed, each thread is executing a single function named "start."  You haven't told us what that function does.  When you're down to one thread you somehow want the work performed by that function to get magically distributed across multiple threads.  Well, that might be possible if every line in the file gets handled separately, or you can re-write your function to chop up the computing task into small independent pieces.  But if there is an interaction between data items, that won't be possible.